# case issue in sql query to generate report

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
leave_id  applicant  from_date   to_date    type   status
1             a       2/7/2014   5/7/2014  Annual  Approve
2           Basudev   2/7/2014   5/7/2014  Annual  Approve
3           Basudev   2/7/2014   5/7/2014  Casual  Approve
4           Basudev   2/7/2014   5/7/2014  Sick    Approve
5             a       2/7/2014   5/7/2014  Casual  Approve
6             a       2/7/2014   5/7/2014  Sick    Approve
```

I want a report like this:

```
applicant  annual  casual  sick
   a         2       4      6
Basudev      1       4
```

I am using this query

```
select a.applicant,
       case when a.type='Annual' 
         Then (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1 
         Else '' 
       End as Annual_consume,
       case when a.type='Casual' 
         Then (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1 
         Else '' 
       End as Casual_consume,
       case when a.type='Sick' 
         Then (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1 
         Else '' 
       End as Sick_consume 
from leaves a 
order by applicant
```

But it is showing data like this:

```
applicant  annual  casual  sick
   a         2    
   a                 4
   a                        6
Basudev              2
Basudev                     3
```

Please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.applicant,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN a.type='Annual'
    THEN (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1
  END) AS Annual_consume,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN a.type='Casual'
    THEN (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1
  END) AS Casual_consume,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN a.type='Sick'
    THEN (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1
  END) AS Sick_consume
FROM leaves a
ORDER BY applicant
GROUP BY applicant
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. can you please tell me how can i join another column from another table. i have another table name leaves_alloc like below. applicant annual_allocate Basudev 18 now i want to add annual_allocate column with upper query using join query..

Comment: Something like this:   SELECT a.applicant, b.annual_allocate SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN a.type='Annual'
    THEN (DATEDIFF(a.to_date,a.from_date))+1
  END) AS Annual_consume,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN a.type='Casual'
    THEN (DATEDIFF(a.to_date,a.from_date))+1
  END) AS Casual_consume,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN a.type='Sick'
    THEN (DATEDIFF(a.to_date,a.from_date))+1
  END) AS Sick_consume FROM leaves a join leaves_alloc b on a.applicant=b.applicant ORDER BY a.applicant
GROUP BY a.applicant, b.annual_allocate

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.applicant,
       sum(case when a.type='Annual' Then (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1 end) as Annual_consume,
       sum(case when a.type='Casual' Then (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1 end) as Casual_consume,
       sum(case when a.type='Sick' Then (DATEDIFF(to_date,from_date))+1 end) as Sick_consume 
from leaves a 
group by a.applicant
order by a.applicant
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. can you please tell me how can i join another column from another table.
i have another table name leaves_alloc like below.
applicant annual_allocate
Basudev    18
now i want to add annual_allocate column with upper query using join query..